# what is difference between uno and dual in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

```
Select *from dual;
Select *from uno;
```

both the queries works fine in Oracle. What is the difference between them?

Comment: The first query selects from table `dual`, the second from table `uno` - so what is your question? However, in Oracle table `dual` is a [special table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries009.htm#SQLRF20036)

Comment: My question is when to use uno and when to use dual. Or, either of them serves the same purpose.

Comment: I guess somebody is just kidding you.

Comment: That is me. I was just curious to know about it.